# Attach a file (Config file) at the time of run docker container from local machine

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-container, docker-image, docker-run

I have created a customised-docker image which runs some code after creating a container.

But I want to attach a config file at the time of deployment and our config file is saved on the local machine.

```
docker run -d -ti -v /home/logs/:/home/logs/ --name "ContainerName" "ImageName" /bin/bash
```

I want to attach file at the place of volume.

How can I attach a config file to the container at runtime?

Comment: the volume /home/logs/ on your docker host is mapped to /home/logs/ on the docker container. Modify files in /home/logs/ and it will be visible in the container. you could fetch config files through curl or from etcd, but that depends on how exotic your needs are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `docker run` options doesnt really let you mess with the image. for that you have the Dockerfile - so you can build an inage of your own, or in this case- kinda like extending the base one:

on your project root directory:

- copy the logs you need to sit inside your project (so the dockerfile can access them)
- create a `Dockerfile`:

  ```
  #Dockerfile

  FROM <image_name>
  COPY ./logs /home/logs
  ```
- build your own image: ( you can also [push it to a repo](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/))

  `docker build . -t <new_image_name>`
- run the container:

  `docker run -d -ti --name "ContainerName" <new_image_name> /bin/bash`

Comment: Thank you @  for your response, your answer is write but I got my answer by this command:
docker run -d -ti -v /home/backup/config/main.json:/home/config/main.json --name "ContainerName" "ImageName" /bin/bash